# I deployed my nextjs 13 app using vercel. However it opens well on most devices except for apple devices

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, next.js13

images hardly load on apple devices and also if they do they are positioned at random places on the website. elements also overlap even though on other devices they dont. any help for me?
link to the website: (https://wislaw-template-fy1wslum6-kennyanyi9.vercel.app/)

I tried opening it on chrome instead of safari yet the problem persisted

The funny thing is that when I simulate the website on apple devices using chrome developer tools and other testing software, the pages appeared perfectly